# UnicodeError when I load dataset with nlp package

Tags: nlp, python-unicode

I encounter a problem when I use `nlp.load_dataset('eli5')`. I don't why my system always tells me:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 2178: illegal multibyte sequence
```

This is my code:

```
import nlp
eli5 = nlp.load_dataset('eli5')
```

But when I write this codes on colab and ubuntu, I don't receive the error.

My python version is 3.8.10.
My system is win 10.

What should I do to work around this error?

Comment: If the error message is any indication, your Windows Python is set up to use GBK as its system encoding. Either configure Python to use UTF-8, or figure out a way to pass the encoding to `load_dataset`. (It doesn't seem to have an easy way to do this, if you are using https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v0.3.0/package_reference/loading_methods.html#nlp.load_dataset)

Comment: This seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/issues/242#issuecomment-641403950
You can maybe try setting `PYTHONUTF8=1` before running your script.